# Problem creating a USB bootable disk for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb-drive, syslinux

I don't understand how to make my usb bootable for installing windows 8.1 pro again as whenever I am trying to make my usb bootable and try to boot from it, the computer  says "no system disk or disk error please replace and strike any key".

I have a hp notebook compaq nc4400.

Comment: It also seems that your Caps Lock is broken .. except from that, this is more a Windows problem than an Ubuntu one.

Comment: wow, can you not use the caps lock key please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Startup Disk creator in Ubuntu to make a bootable USB disk. **You need a Windows 8 Pro ISO and Product key for this to work**

1. Open the Startup Disk creator
   [image]
2. When the application loads, insert you USB stick (it must be at least 4 gb for the 32 bit version and at least 8 gb for the 64 bit version). Then select your USB under *disk to use* and your Windows 8 Pro ISO file under *source disk image*.
   [image]
3. Click make startup disk and wait for the process to complete
4. When it's done, restart you computer and boot from your newly created Windows 8 bootable USB. The windows installer should load.

Welcome to closed source proprietary software!

Image credits go to [Ubuntu Tutorials](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview)